# C how to modify memory of structs that are inside other structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

If I have two structs:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int time;
    double rate;

}quote;

typedef struct{

    unsigned int freeSlots;
    unsigned int end;
    unsigned int start;
    unsigned int currSize;
    unsigned int maxSize;
    unsigned int startAt;
    //unsigned int currIndex;
    quote quoteBuffer[1];

}cbuf;
```

And I wanted to make a function that would modify the size of the quoteBuffer array inside cbuf, how exactly would I go about doing that? I have tried a few approaches but none have worked so far. I keep returning to the same format of:

```
quote *newQuoteBuffer = malloc(sizeof(quote) * newSize);
```

And if I already have an existing cbuf somewhere (for example, we will call it "a" where a is the pointer to the cbuf):

```
a->quoteBuffer = newQuoteBuffer;
```

But obviously this doesn't work. Any hints?

Comment: `quote quoteBuffer[1]` what's the significance of this?

Comment: And you can't change the `cbuf` structure? So that `quoteBuffer` is a pointer for example?

Comment: To initialize the array of quotes inside the cbuf struct. I suppose I could also do quote quoteBuffer[]. but I used 1 since I was going to modify the size later on with malloc.

Comment: better have a pointer to quote instead of array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg such as quote *quoteBuffer; inside of the cbuf struct?

Comment: Yes. Then you could just do two allocations initially (one for the `cbuf` structure and one for its contained `quoteBuffer`). Later when you need to reallocate, it's easy to make `quoteBuffer` to point to the new buffer, no reallocation needed for the `cbuf` structure.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
quote quoteBuffer[1];
```

should be:

```
quote *quoteBuffer;
```

Then the assignment will work.

Dereferencing `quote` looks like this:

```
a->quoteBuffer->time;
```

If you later have multiple elements of quote allocated with malloc() you can access them like this:

```
a->quoteBuffer[i].time;
```

Comment: and if I wanted to replace the current quoteBuffer with a new one, would it simply be cbuf->quoteBuffer = newBuffer?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to free() it first, or you create a leak. And of course it's always a good idea to initialize it to NULLif not used.

Comment: @Devolus free() the original quoteBuffer first? So free(cbuf->quoteBuffer) and then cbuf->quoteBuffer = newBuffer?

Comment: Yes. To be safe you should initialize it to NULL, and before you free you do `if(a->buffer) free(a->buffer); a->buffer = malloc(new size);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure of how many elements will go into the quoteBuffer, maintain a linked list of the same. For that

```
quote *quoteBuffer;
```

And keep adding or removing the elements to/from the buffer as required.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the point of why someone would have the last element of a struct as a single element array.   This is a trick that's used in old C code as a way to make the struct size variable length.

You can write code such as this:

```
Bitmapset *p = malloc(offsetof(Bitmapset, quoteBuffer) + n * sizeof(quote));
```

Then you write code like this:

```
p->quoteBuffer[0]
```

up to:

```
p->quoteBuffer[n-1]
```

You do not want to assign a pointer directly to quoteBuffer, as you guessed.

So, why would you want to declare quoteBuffer as:
    quote quoteBuffer[1];
instead of
    quote* quoteBuffer;
?

It's because you do not wanna to have a separate allocation for quoteBuffer.  A single allocation can be used for the entire cbuf, including the inline quote array.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. One is to use a pointer in cbuf, as others have mentioned, by changing

```
quote quoteBuffer[1];
```

to

```
quote* quoteBuffer;
```

The other is to resize the cbuf:

```
#include <stddef.h> // for offsetof

struct cbuf* realloc_cbuf(struct cbuf* cbufp, size_t nquotes)
{
    struct cbuf* new_cbufp = realloc(cbufp, offsetof(struct cbuf, quoteBuffer) + nquotes * sizeof *cbufp->quoteBuffer);
    if (!new_cbufp)
    {
        // handle out of memory here. cbufp is still intact so free it if you don't need it.
    }
    return new_cbufp;
}

void elsewhere(void)
{
    struct cbuf* acbuf = NULL;
    acbuf = realloc_cbuf(1);
    acbuf = realloc_cbuf(10);
    // etc. 
}
```